Using osm/mbt file with TileServer GL
I'm currently trying to set up an own tile server with tileserver gl. The setup itself went pretty straight forward, but now I'm stuck during the import of the data. The data I want to use is available in 2 formats. As a .osm.gz or as a .mbt file. As far I understand tileserver gl needs the file in an .mbtiles format.
I tried different methods to convert the osm file. trying to convert it first to an .osm.pbf file and then to an .mbtiles file fials with the error Can't read shapefiles unless a bounding box is provided.
Also I couldn't find out how I ca use the .mbt file. I searched quite a while but didn't found out a solution.
Can somebody tell me how I can make it happen that the tileserver gl can read this kind of data?
